# Double headings in latex

Tags: latex

I have a problem with latex. I want to create a heading with a special name and aumomatic numbering of the chapters.

I use the \chapter{Introduction} command to create the chapter named Introduction. In the Content it is listed as "1 Introduction" which is right. In the text I get two headings. The first is "Chapter 1" and under that I get "Introduction". So actually the \chapter generates two headings. What can I do?

Comment: What do you want it to look like? `\chapter{Introduction}` should create a single `1 Introduction` on the chapter page rather than `Chapter 1` followed by "another heading" `Introduction`?

Comment: Exacly, thats what I want =) Sorry, I forgot to mention that

Comment: You should consider providing the community with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`. Are you currently using any packages that influence the sectional units of your document?

Comment: \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}  


\begin{document} 


\tableofcontents


\chapter{ChapterName}


\end{document}

Sorry, for the bad structuring. I have no idea how to make a new line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default layout when using a `\chapter` in `report` or `book`. You need to update `\@makechapterhead` in order to achieve the layout you're after:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}% <cmd>
  {\@chapapp\space\thechapter\par\nobreak\vskip 20\p@}% <search>
  {\Huge\thechapter\space}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{ChapterName}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also look at [MemoirChapterStyles](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/memoirchapterstyles) or [fncychap](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fncychap?lang=en) for a whole bunch of different chapter heading styles that you could use without having to redefine `\@makechapterhead` by hand.

Comment: Quite possibly so. Unfortunately I'm too new on here to be allowed a comment if I haven't posted the original question or answer: that privilege requires reputation 50. I thought my addition was borderline comment/answer to begin with, and upon finding I was unable to comment I wrote it as an answer. Sorry.